# sql query with dynamic headers using case when

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is what I am trying to solve for (picture at link) -

2. How would you query this table, named table1, to produce the results below it?

[image: transform]

I am stuck on creating the dynamic headers. Basic jist of where I'm at is below.

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN Color = 'Blue' THEN COUNT(ID)
END AS 'no_of_blue'

CASE
    WHEN Color = 'Red' THEN COUNT(ID) 
END AS 'no_of_red'

CASE
    WHEN Color = 'Green' THEN COUNT(ID)
END AS 'no_of_green'
```

Comment: You need *conditional aggregation* where `COUNT` is emulated with `SUM`:  `SUM(CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Blue'
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
           END) 'no_of_blue',
       SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Red'
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
           END) 'no_of_red',
       SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Green'
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
           END) 'no_of_green'
```

or PIVOT may also be useful